# How to remove the capitalization of names

Tags: cv, capitalization, resume

I would like my name to not be entirely in uppercase.

This is my .tex file.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\name{Aston Martin} % Your name
```

This is my .cls file.

```
\ProvidesClass{resume}[]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default
```

The name would currently come up as: "ASTON MARTIN".

However, I would like it to be formatted like this: "Aston Martin".

Comment: There must be something else that is causing this. Could you please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than the current code-snippet(s)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx.  Where is your `resume.cls` from? There isn't such a class on CTAN, and the one [here](https://people.debian.org/~dburrows/resume-cls.html) doesn't seem to be the same one.  So you need to do two things: turn your TeX file into a complete minimal document (just enough to show the problem, and nothing more) and post a link to the complete `resume.cls` that you are using.

Comment: This is a little late. But if you look into the `\def \printname` in the resume.cls, there should be a `\MakeUppercase` in that defination. Removing it should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are using the `resume.cls` found [here](https://github.com/treyhunner/resume/blob/master/resume.cls). Add the following to  your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\namesize\bfseries \@name}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```